# Why is there resonance at 0 field in optical pumping?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In optical pumping, when the net magnetic field, earth’s field and the applied field, is 0 and the RF generator is off, how come resonance occurs?

Comment: In theory or in experiment?

Comment: In the experiment.